# Node project error 'internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888' on Vps OVH

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vps, ovh

i have nodejs project work well in local but when upload it on Vps i find this errors
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is stated right there in the console. `Cannot find module ../modules/user`. You are referencing a file that does not exist. The file may exist in your local environment but does not exist in your vps or does not exist in the same directory as referenced.

Comment: i rename the file